# How to make forms to not resize on tablet on phone

Tags: css, html, mobile, tablet

I am trying to make the admin panel of my cms accessible from any device, and I have it working except for one issue...

Pages with a form (e.g. to edit page content) that is taller then fits in the screen, automatically gets resized in any mobile browser, making it tiny and forcing user to zoom in.

Does anybody have a work around on this?

Im using a fluid design, width=100% etc. All other pages display fine, even if content is more then initial screen. The problem occurs only with forms that are longer. Small forms with only 2 or 3 input fields display fine.

Thank you very much for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding the following meta tag to your html:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, name="viewport">
```

And you can use this instead to prevent the user from zooming

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
```

Comment: Any issues I should now look out for, with user scalability turned off?

Comment: I have done some redesigning and now it works with your first line, <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, name="viewport">. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad i can help, and in case you chose to stop user scalability the only thing you should look out for is if the font-size is readable in all the site. Because the user wont be able to zoom in if it wasn't.